# Reinforcement learning reward waiting list

Tags: reinforcement-learning

In reinforcement learning (RL), we design the reward function so that the agent can learn the optimal policy. In my problem the agent is the manager of a waiting list, I have T ressources that i want to allocate to N subjects each one at stage j. How can i specify the reward function in this context so that the the utility of all the customers is maximized ?

Comment: do you mean "the sum of utilities of all the customers is maximied?"

Comment: yes the sum of utilities of all the customers is maximized after the final stage.

Comment: sounds like you should set the reward to be the sum of customer utilities then